# Fetch Private Repositories information using github API

Tags: github-api

I am trying to get the list of all my github repositories using this API.
`https://api.github.com/users/<user>/repos/?access_token=<auth_token>`

This API returns only public repositories and not the private ones too though I am adding auth_token as a query parameter.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are those private repositories *your* repositories? By default, you only see repositories of which you are the owner, not those of which you are 'just' a member. So if you have a company account that is the owner, and you are a member of the company, you probably won't see the company repositories unless you specify `type=member`. [repos docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories). There is also an api to [get organisation repos](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories).

Comment: If you want *your* repositories, the GitHub API recommends using the [`GET /user/repos`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories) endpoint, instead of the [`GET /users/:username/repos`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories) endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. 
The access token that you create must have some permissions/scope enabled.

The scope that is required for reading private repositories are user, repo.

You should also be finding this in your request headers as - `X-OAuth-Scopes → user, repo`